# Where and when did the numerical time units (hours) originate?

Tags: history, calendar, time, provenance

The Torah states no numerical divisions for the day. The closest numeric we find is that there are 7 days in the week, and that the start of the "day" begins with "erev" (and there are debates on when that begins.) When and from where did the concept, in Judaism, of dividing the day into 12 "parts" called a "sha'ah" begin? We see such a concept in discussions of when to burn chametz and when to stop eating it (on erev Pesach), for example.

Comment: Babylon. Who said there is any Jewish significance to that division?

Comment: The gemoro does say that the planets 'change' every hour. So it is not just a means of dividing the day. It does have some purpose and Jewish significance

Comment: DanF, without indicating in the question that Judaism divides the day into 12 hours (does it? where?), this question seems to have nothing to do with Judaism at all.

Comment: @preferred Judaism uses hours because everyone else does. We could have used microseconds or petaseconds.

Comment: @msh210 The Talmud describes how Adam was created; in each hour one thing happens.

Comment: @Double AA   what about the gemoro in shabbos I mentioned. Also rosh hashono.

Comment: @ msh210 ditto,

Comment: @Ypnypn You mean how one thing happens every 3600000000 microseconds?

Comment: @DoubleAA The fact is, it wasn't 3500,000,000 microseconds, but rather an amount of time which fits well into hours. This may indicate something.

Comment: @Ypnypn It may indicate that God wanted to evenly divide the 12 things he had to do that day. (BTW there is very little reason to believe that Aggada is meant to be literal, in which case you have no question at all.)

Comment: *start of the "day" begins with "erev"* - This is disputed as well, at least in theory.  (See Rashbam on Bereishit.)